# Find rows where column1 matches column2 (possibly in an another row)

Tags: sql, sql-server, intersect

Say I have some code below from a table called Table1.

```
Column1   | Column2
41391175  | 41000
41523664  | 41523
110505116 | 110509
110453629 | 110505
41000     | 351592
```

Column1 and Column2 are `NVARCHAR(10)`. What I want to return is all entries in Column 1 where Column2 is IN Column1, so I want a result to look like this-

```
Column1
41523664
110505116
41000
```

Right now, this is what my code would look like-

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table1
INTERSECT  
SELECT Column2
FROM Table1 ;
```

But as of right now, that only finds the EXACT same number as in Column2, rather than one that Column1 contains inside it, so I would just get this result-

```
Column1

41000
```

Is there a way to work around this, or to get an IN clause within INTERSECT? I haven't been able to find something that does that after some research.

Comment: What are the datatypes of column1 and 2?

Comment: Column 1 has the entry 41523664 and Column 2 has 41523, so because 41523 is IN 41523664(in this case, it's the first five digits), I want 41523664 to return. Does that make sense? Let me know if it is still not clearly seen in the post.

Comment: Both are nvarchar(10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can match them using LIKE operator:

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table1 AS t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table1 AS x
    WHERE t.Column1 LIKE x.Column2 + '%'
)
```

[**Demo on DB Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8c0644a266dab0201906fd543b7dd677)

Answer (score 0):

```
select c1.column1 from table1 c1 inner join (select distinct column2 from table1) c2 on charindex(c2.column2, c1.column1) = 1
```